# Javascript download a file and read back modified

Tags: javascript, browser, fileapi

Although we cant just access arbitrary files from the users disk I am wanting to
have a system where user downloads a file then edits it and uploads the edited file.
So
user clicks link that downloads a file.
user open file and edits it
user saves the file
javascript uploads the edited file back to the server

Comment: What kinds of files and where are you having issues?

Comment: Kinds of files would be excel, word, pdf, text.

Comment: Issue is to have the browser upload the file it just downloaded after the user edits the file

Comment: The best you can do, if you don't want to provide an in-browser editor, is have the user submit the file via form after they've made the changes. Page content is sandboxed away from the operating system for security.

Comment: I felt like given the browser has privileged access to the file due to it having downloaded it, I would use that privileged access to re upload it